# Split Big Matrix into Submatrices

Tags: latex

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\jot}{8pt}

\usepackage{mathtools}

% Title Page
\title{FORMULÁRIO}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \allowdisplaybreaks
        \left[\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4}^{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4}^{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{10} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}
        \end{matrix} \right.\\ -> HERE
        \left.\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8}^{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8}^{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}
        \end{matrix}\right. \\ ->HERE
        \left.\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10}^{2}
        \end{matrix}\right] 
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I have a single big matrix which I want to split into small submatrices in order to fit the page width. The problem in this code is that the submatrices stay side by side and there is no paragraph break in the expected 'HERE' points. If they go side by side they don't fit the page width.

Answer (score 1):

if this what you are looking for:
[image]

the latex code would be:

```
\tiny
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
        \allowdisplaybreaks
        &\left[\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4}^{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4}^{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{10} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{3} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}
        \end{matrix} \right].\\
                        &\left[\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8}^{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8}^{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{5} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{6} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{7} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}
        \end{matrix}\right]. \\
                        &\left[\begin{matrix}
            h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{1} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{1} \phi_{10}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{2} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{2}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{3} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{3}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{4} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{4}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{5} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{5}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{6} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{6}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{7} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{7}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{8} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{8}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{2121} \phi_{9}^{2} & h^{f}_{2111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9}\\h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1121} \phi_{10} \phi_{9} & h^{f}_{1111} \phi_{10}^{2}
        \end{matrix}\right] 
                \end{split}
    \end{equation}
```

I used tiny to fit it in one page and split environment to break the matrics

Answer (score 0):

With the \multline environment I could solve this problem and split a big single matrix into 2 small ones and obtain the following result:

[image: A single big matrix splitted into 2 small ones]

```
\begin{multline}
    \noindent
    \allowdisplaybreaks
    \tilde{h}_{\alpha \beta}^{sz} \phi_q (\xi_1^s, \xi_2^s) \phi_r (\xi_1^z, \xi_2^z) = \\*
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{1 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 1}_{2 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
        \end{pmatrix} \\*
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{1 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 1}_{2 2} \phi_{3}^{2}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{pmatrix} \\*
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{1 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
            \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{1 2}_{2 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
        \end{pmatrix} \\*
        \begin{pmatrix}
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{1 2} \phi_{3}^{2} \\
            \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{1} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{2} \phi_{3} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 1} \phi_{3}^{2} & \tilde{h}^{2 2}_{2 2} \phi_{3}^{2}
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \
\end{multline}
```